# connection refused error while accessing adapter from app

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have an adapter on my worklight server which is publicly hosted and my adapter is using some external ip  `164.100.XXX.XX:9090` , now when i am trying to access that adapter from my mobile phone i am getting following error in logs

> 11-19 03:47:01.499: E/NONE(2363): Procedure invocation error. Runtime:
>   Http request failed: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException:
>   Connect to 164.100.XXX.XX:9090 [/164.100.XXX.XX] failed: Connection
>   refused: connect

what do i need to configure on worklight server to unlock ip and port

Comment: You need your server to be online and reachable.

Comment: my server is already online , i can access it from browser

Comment: i have another adapter which is working fine but this external ip is not working

Comment: You put 164.100.XXX.XX:9090 in your browser, in the same device and it works??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not configure anything in the MobileFirst Server for this.

If an IP address is not available, that means it is not really the correct IP address to use... you need to double-check the IP address and its port. You need to verify that's really an external, public, IP address. 164.0.0... does not seem external at all.